# How to track AJAX site search using Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I'm using AJAX (POST method) for my site search. Here's my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        search_phrase: search_phrase
    },
    success: function(data) { ...
```

My aim is to use Google Analytics to start tracking search terms. Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your success callback lodge a [virtual pageview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#virtual-pageviews) with Google Analytics. Overwrite the page page for that pageview to include a query parameter (unlike KayKay's answer I'm assuming Universal Analytics):

```
success: function(data) { 
  ga('send', 'pageview', 'search.php?q=mykeyword');
  .........
```

(there is not enough info about yor page code to see how to retrieve the keyword - either read it with jQuery from your search input field, or you can extract it from the ajax request).

This will count every search as a pageview, but since searching replaces the content that makes sense IMO.

Set up internal site search in your views to work with (in my example) the "q" parameter (and click "remove search parameter from url").

If you do not want to touch your ajax function you can use [global ajax event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) from jQuery, but that's a bit harder to set up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm displaying search results on my homepage so am not using search.php. Does this look right to you? `ga('send', 'pageview', '?q=' + search_term)`

Comment: Yes - it does not matter how the page is called, the important thing is that the query parameter is present (and that you data view is configured to use it for internal search).

Comment: If I didn't want to record each search as a page view, could I use the 'event' hit type for this instead?

Comment: I don't think so, but then I have never tested it (some parts of the search reports tie search terms to page level data so it certainly would change the meaning of the reports).

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger a google analytics event when sendind the ajax call. This is done as shown in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) using :

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'YourAjaxCallName', 'The posted value as a string']);
```

Comment: I think the syntax for sending virtual pageviews has changed?

Comment: What's the new syntax..? I think this is the best amswer to a basic ajax trigger.. But if it jas changed, can someone share a method assuming analytics script is running in default?